# Sprite occlusion sequence error occurs when using Sprite Shader

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, vertex-shader, shader-graph

I tried to render Sprite shadow with the Shader Graph.

But as you can see, the tree is rendered mistakenly before the house.

[The tree is rendered before the house](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8a71c.png)

[You can see that the tree is actually at the end of these sprites](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icEF9.png)

And here's the Shader Graph that I'm using for my game:
[Shader Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IcDm.png)

I am totally an amateur in shader and Shader Graph. What's wrong with my shader or is there any way that I could render them correctly?

I tried to set Depth Write to Force Enabled, the occlusion is now correct, but it just hide the UI in Canvas. So I bet it would be a depth buffer problem.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my question: It's not an issue of Shader but an issue of Sort Mode.

#### Solution

- Delete URP asset.
- Set **Sort Mode** to **Default** from *Project Settings > Graphics*.

#### Reason for the issue

I converted my game from 2D to 3D with URP installed so that the **Sort Mode** was set to **Custom Axis** with Vector3(0,1,0).
After having installed the URP, the sort mode settings were hidden by URP. And I have switched the *Universal Renderer* (AKA 3D renderer) so that the settings cannot be modified. It's only applicable to the 2D renderer.